# Scaling a Meteor app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, meteor

In an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103603/scalability-of-a-meteor-app), it's noted that "Apps deployed to the hosted servers with 'meteor deploy' do not yet have any guarantees or SLAs about scaling." So that rules out the possibility of using their hosted servers if I want to be sure I can fully scale, now.

The answer further notes that "A server bundle generated with 'meteor bundle' is basically a single process app. It is up to you wire it up to multiple instances, or however you want to implement auto-scaling."

After reading that, I'm still very unclear on the question of scaling. On Heroku, I assume I can run "meteor bundle" single process apps in dynos. But if I use many dynos, each running a Meteor server bundle, is Meteor designed so that they can be wired up so that they are all synchronized with the same data (even if there's a lag)?

Comment: I think meteor saves it's mongo instance in the filesystem. So the solution would be configure it to use an external database. I don't know how (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question, the Meteor team has announced a [roadmap](https://trello.com/card/multitier-server-architecture-support-very-large-numbers-of-simultaneous-clients/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/46) which includes the scalability plans, for inclusion in Meteor 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor is still very young platform. Before scalability,personally i would put question of security, as Meteor right now is having no security model in public release. Also no mention of security in Meteor docs, but Meteor team has confirmed that they are working on it, and future release will have it. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100813/when-can-we-expect-data-validation-and-security-in-meteor

So I think you and I (for security implementation) have to wait for more releases and perhaps before 1.0 scalability will be handled internally, or atlease they should have documentation explaining how to do that.

To get some idea about, how scalability will be handled and to get better picture on it, I think someone from meteor team should answer about scalability.

Comment: Yeah -- I've been aware of the security issue as well, but there's been a fair amount of discussion of that already (and it's also been stated that "most" of the meteor team is working on it, and today there's even some software: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/meteor-core/g4Bsm3yFTe4). So I've been feeling pretty optimistic about the security issue. But the question of scalability really hasn't been addressed to anything like the same degree, at least that I've been able to see. So I thought the question was worth asking.

Comment: agree about validity of question and your concerns for scalability, Would love to hear something from Meteor team. I will try on Meteor IRC.

Comment: As of October 2012, Meteor at version 0.5.0 has an official authentication module included and documented.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy meteor apps into Heroku but you need to stick with 1 dyno. Because Heroku does not support WebSockets or Sticky Sessions.

So you need to find another PAAS provider. Nodejitsu is a good option.If you wan't to scale into multiple instances, you need to find a way to sync write operations between instances.

Then You'll need [Meteor Cluster](http://goo.gl/2aHJ2) - http://goo.gl/2aHJ2

Answer (score 0):

I recently asked a similar question ([Which PaaS would be best for a Meteor JS app that needs to be scalable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467938/which-paas-would-be-best-for-a-meteor-js-app-that-needs-to-be-scalable)), and one of the answers explained the Heroku situation very well (I thought) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468418/2311632 .  It is also pointed out (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468609/2311632) that one could deploy on meteor.com. While scaling is still on the roadmap, presumably they have or are addressing some scaling issues 'in-house', or can otherwise keep their service at the cutting edge of what's possible in scaling for Meteor Apps.  Otherwise, you could go with EC2 and scale vertically (boost the power of a single instance) until Meteor hits the mark with official scaling solutions.  Getting set up with EC2 is new to me, but this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16468826/2311632) looks like a good starting point. I haven't tried it yet, but likely will soon.